# Python Discord bot client.user = None

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to write a Discord bot in **Spyder4 (Python v3.8.8)**. I couldn't make the bot connect, even after I just **copy and pasted** code from tutorials on internet. Then I dug a little bit and found that the bot seemingly don't recognize the token or username.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('tkn.env')
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()
print(f'{client.user} woke up.')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.run(TOKEN, bot=False)
input("oho")
```

So, the `f'{client.user} woke up.'` part is to see the user name, and the program returns `None`, so it writes like `'None woke up'`.

I also added `"input('oho')"` to see the message for a longer time, kind of like pause command in C or `Console.Read()` in C#.

There's no hole between `TOKEN`, `=` and the value in `tkn.env` file.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Also, the `client.run()` hangs up the entire program and I don't know what to do.

Comment: What library is this? Is this Spyder4? If so, I can't find any resources on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I know what your problem is. See, `client.user` is None before the client logs on. Please look [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.user) for further clarification. As explained, the user attribute will return `None` if the bot has not logged on, which in that state, still hasn't. Try moving that line to the `on_ready()` function. It should look a bit like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} woke up.')
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
```

Although I don't see why you need that line since you have another line pretty similar, though I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access client.user before the bot logs in. Move it to the on_ready event:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} woke up.')
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
```